# Axon test fails when an aggregate field type is Set -> HashSet

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I fell down in a weird (at least for me) failure when using `Set` instead `List` to hold a collection of objects.

> I was able to reproduce the issue in this public [repo](https://github.com/habutre/axonsample) so that I hope might be helpful to give a real case to help understand better.

For some reason the hash table of my `hashset` differs among test lifecycle, I mean event by event being applied when a command comes my collection of `Schedules` differs although the values are the same.

The test result is:

```
org.axonframework.test.AxonAssertionError: Illegal state change detected! Property "com.acme.axonsample.axonsample.WorkDay" has different value when sourcing events.
Working aggregate value:     <WorkDay(id=workDay-for-2020-01-02, day=2020-01-02, schedules=[Schedule(id=5dca3df439881c002543876e, workDuration=PT41M, begin=2020-01-02T10:00Z, end=2020-01-02T11:00Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T09:45Z, stop=2020-01-02T10:35Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z)]]), Schedule(id=7dca3bf439881c002543836b, workDuration=PT1H, begin=2020-01-02T12:00Z, end=2020-01-02T13:00Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z)]]), Schedule(id=2dca3be439871c022543836a, workDuration=PT45M, begin=2020-01-02T14:00Z, end=2020-01-02T14:45Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T13:58Z, stop=2020-01-02T14:45Z)]])], workLogs=[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T09:45Z, stop=2020-01-02T10:35Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T13:58Z, stop=2020-01-02T14:45Z)])>
Value after applying events: <WorkDay(id=workDay-for-2020-01-02, day=2020-01-02, schedules=[Schedule(id=7dca3bf439881c002543836b, workDuration=PT1H, begin=2020-01-02T12:00Z, end=2020-01-02T13:00Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z)]]), Schedule(id=2dca3be439871c022543836a, workDuration=PT45M, begin=2020-01-02T14:00Z, end=2020-01-02T14:45Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T13:58Z, stop=2020-01-02T14:45Z)]]), Schedule(id=5dca3df439881c002543876e, workDuration=PT41M, begin=2020-01-02T10:00Z, end=2020-01-02T11:00Z, workLogs=Optional[[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T09:45Z, stop=2020-01-02T10:35Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z)]])], workLogs=[WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T09:45Z, stop=2020-01-02T10:35Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T10:54Z, stop=2020-01-02T13:00Z), WorkLog(start=2020-01-02T13:58Z, stop=2020-01-02T14:45Z)])>
```

I didn't find on documentation any restrictions to use `Set` even though I got stuck with that failure. Set is important to me in order to guarantee no duplications

Comment: Does the `WorkDay` class, and all objects contained in it, implement a correct `equals` method?

Comment: Maybe it is importrant for a framework, that collection actually stores the last added element. Maybe you should override Set so that add() method will replace old value with new.

Comment: @Steven I am using _Lombok_ and `equals` and `hashcode` are implemented by this lib, I also tried `equals` and `hashcode` from IntelliJ. When I hacked it with a equals that check `Set` elements by its values all works fine, but sound like a ugly hack. Using `List` works fine. @yuri-nevinitsin I believe Axon should take care of it not client code

Comment: The framework should deal with this perfectly fine, but apparently it doesn't... I've checked out your sample project and noticed the same thing. I'm diving in to this and will come back to you once I have a conclusion.

Comment: According to @allard "The test fixtures use a special deep-equals method to check for equality of Aggregate state. Basically, it checks all the equality of the fields. As long as the values in the fields don't override Object's equals() method, it uses field equality. The issue here is that Java's collection implementations all override equals(). Their implementation then checks for equals methods on your entity objects.

You can switch this mechanism off (at your own risk) by calling setReportIllegalStateChange(false) on the fixture."

Comment: @RogérioRamos, do you feel Allard's answer was sufficient to tackle your problem? I know this part, hence why I asked if you implemented a dedicated equals/hashcode method. Maybe it works if you do not use Lombok's version but provide your own which tests all the fields?

Comment: @Steven I guess it solve the issue, but I want to highlight I have used not only Lombok implementation but also Apache commons-lang and java.util.Objects.equals and hashCode same result. My best guess is that the hashCode using only the ID field will work as expected. Anyway, Allard's answer could be most suitable answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am still pretty confused that none of those options did the trick at first... Regardless, I am pleased to hear you've resolved the issue for now.

Comment: @RogérioRamos, might be nice to describe the answer Allard gave you on the user group issue. That'll help others on StackOverflow when they encounter a similar problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/axonframework/OnfWyP6g8vA

Answer (score 0):

According to the Axon creator the main issue is related to hashCode that in my cases is generated using Lombok.

To solve the issue, the code below will work as expected:

```
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(id);
 }
```

The whole thread can be read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/axonframework/OnfWyP6g8vA)

PS:. Since I would like to keep using Lombok and I have tested with others `equals` and `hashCode` generators facing the same issue, I kept my implementation with `List` instead `Set`